# Location for archiving on iPhone

Tags: iphone, archive, nskeyedarchiver

I'm looking to archive some nested NSDictionary objects to be able to use the data in them at next start. To do so I was going to use `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: toFile: ]` but was not sure where to put the file. In the archiving docs, the examples put the file in `NSTemporaryDirectory()` but for persistent data, a temporary directory does not seem to make much sense. I've had a look around but can't find where would be the best place to put it unless `NSDocumentDirectory` is for use by apps for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for persistent file storage:

- NSDocumentDirectory if you want files to be backed up by iTunes
- NSCachesDirectory if you don't want to backup those files to improve device synchronizing time or for some other reasons - e.g. some files that can be easily recreated when needed

Answer (score 0):

what i know is that preferences you save in the "Library/Preferences" directory.
Other data which should persist should be saved in the "Documents" directory.
(if you have the book "iphone programming" from the big nerd ranch you will find a good description in chapter 14)

bye

Comment: oh, Vladimir was faster ;). and right, there is also the "Library/Caches" directory, which for me doesn't make so much sense because it's not backup as Vladimir described it.